# Your project must have a `package` set in the Expo config

Tags: reactjs, eas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6M56.png) I am currently experiencing the error message: Your project must have a `package` set in the Expo config (app.json). Although this property has a value on the app.json. How do I resolve this.

Checked the app.json. The property was available on the app.json.

Comment: I know you say you have checked, but you still need to edit your post with the `app.json`. We have nothing to go off otherwise.

Comment: Used https://github.com/expo/fyi/blob/main/eas-vcs-workflow.md to resolve the issue

Comment: [Please post code/errors/etc as formatted text instead of links to images of formatted text.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)